# How to draw a dfa for this language :L={ w | w has an even number of a’s and one or two b’s}

Tags: finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa

I tried this problem but i get stuck everytime because i am unable to satisfy the second condition for b. Someone give the right dfa diagram for the language.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where have you been getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
[image: DFA for even number of a and 1 or 2 b]
Just rename the states with whatever you feel appropriate.